# Double select html

Tags: html, input, dropdown, user-input, html-select

Is it possible to achieve a double select like this with html? It is like having two dropdowns in parallel as shown in the figure below.

[image: screenshot from ios]

Comment: So, do you want that when 1min is selected, 0s should be automatically selected and when 2min is selected, 5s should be automatically selected. Is that what you want?

Comment: those are two independently scrollable elements and you could create that via quite some amount of CSS but natively there's no component that would visually give you that, although you can always place two distinct selects beside each other.

Comment: Oh I see, I may just put an input where the user enters the time manually. I expected that as I have been doing some research. Thank you!